# APInvoice Doc Type

Tags: acumatica

When creating an AP Invoice, there are 3 types (Bill, Credit Adjustment, Debit Adjustment and Prepayment). Is this extensible to add another different type? I checked the DAC and the DocType property has the following attribute [APInvoiceType.List()]. Perhaps it is somehow possible to change/enhance this attribute?

Comment: I would suggest another approach rather than redefining that field because the framework makes use of it for business rules. Methods of the framework that checks that field could exhibit undefined behavior if it's redefined. You could make a new field with default types and your own types. Hide original field and replace it with your field. When user changes your field, change the original field in the graph. For your new  DocType you should set the original field to the default stock type that makes the most sense. Processes will continue to treat the invoice based on stock types.

Comment: Thanks - sounds like a good approach